# What is the name of the survey question style that forces a choice between non-opposite pairs of items, and why is it used?

Tags: statistics, test, data, experiment-design, survey

I've seen personality tests and industrial / organizational psychology tests that force one to choose between non-opposing concepts. What is the name of this question style, and what are the reasons to use it over a more standard question style that forces you to choose between opposing pairs?

Example questions:

In general, I prefer [Assertiveness / Clear communication]

I prefer my direct reports to be [Self-directed / Punctual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
Forced-choice task

**Background**
You have answered your own question:

> ...tests that force one to choose...

Such tests are generally referred to as **[forced-choice tests](http://www.cis.rit.edu/people/faculty/montag/vandplite/pages/chap_4/ch4p5.html)** in psychophysics. There are many applications of these tests. In general, AFC tasks are less biased than for example yes/no tasks [(Yushurun *et al*, 2008)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1207/s15327043hup1803_4?casa_token=TZFMPieMBMYAAAAA:JCu0eiMcstIaQVOEy7P_lYYi5YtfUsFrQ5CIoyV5QqEL3LRHcNBLfkdURSrfomzVfOdVgQL73xMA). A sample paper on an AFC test for personality testing is [Christiansen *et al*. (2005)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698908002599).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Christiansen *et al*. *Human Performance* (2005); **18**(3): 267-307](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698908002599)

**-**  [yushurun *et al*. *Vis Res* (2008); **48**(17): 1837-51](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1207/s15327043hup1803_4?casa_token=TZFMPieMBMYAAAAA:JCu0eiMcstIaQVOEy7P_lYYi5YtfUsFrQ5CIoyV5QqEL3LRHcNBLfkdURSrfomzVfOdVgQL73xMA)</sub>

Comment: It's my understanding that forced-choice also refers to yes / no, A / B, less / more, or similar formats, yes? I'm more interested in the non-opposite or unrelated pairing aspect of the questions than the two-option answer aspect. Is there even a word to describe the specific type of question that pairs options that lie on entirely unrelated axes? Or am I mistaken in thinking that forced-choice refers to all of them?

Comment: @BenNilsson - I think they apply to all, given the linked Christiansen paper, but I am unsure to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Like AliceD's answer says, this is a form of forced-choice task used to assay preferences.

These measures are used especially when there is no good counterpart on the opposite side: there is no spectrum to consider. Let's think about your examples:

> In general, I prefer [Assertiveness / Clear communication]
>
> I prefer my direct reports to be [Self-directed / Punctual]

What would the "opposite" versions of these be? Some possibilities:

> In general, I prefer [Assertiveness / Passiveness]
>
> In general, I prefer [Opaque communication / clear communication]
>
> I prefer my direct reports to be [Self-directed / Micromanaged]
>
> I prefer my direct reports to be [Late / Punctual]

With the exception of maybe the third one (level of oversight), the counterparts are not really that informative. No one wants their employees to be *late*, but someone might not mind so much if someone is *late* as long as they manage themselves. The test is trying to get at what your desires are when you weight dissimilar things against each other.

Another example might be food preferences: are sweet and sour opposites?

What about someone that likes, say, fruit flavors - those are both *sweet* and *sour* - you need a way to find that someone prefers sweet+sour over savory, or to find that another person likes sweet and savory foods, but doesn't like sour ones.

Other options in this circumstance might be to rank-order possibilities, but in general giving people just 2 options allows them to more quickly make a determination. You can develop rank orders later by analyzing the results of the individual paired items.